# Why am I getting System.Security.AccessControl.PrivilegeNotHeldException in my WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, security

I have a simple *WPF* application which is trying to find the *ActiveDirectory* groups a given user is a member of. The code for retrieving the groups is:

```
public static HashSet<string> GetUserGroups(string userLogon)
{
    var groups = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    var identity = new WindowsIdentity(userLogon);

    if (identity.Groups == null) { return groups; }

    var type = typeof(NTAccount);

    foreach (var group in identity.Groups)
    {
        groups.Add(group.Translate(type).ToString());
    }

    return groups;
}
```

However when I try running this at the startup of the app, I get the following exception thrown when the method tries to create the `new WindowsIdentity(userLogon)`:

> System.Security.AccessControl.PrivilegeNotHeldException: 'The process
>   does not possess the 'SeTcbPrivilege' privilege which is required for
>   this operation.'

Not this does not happen if I run the code in a `Console` app. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: have you tried to run this application as administrator? was the consolapp run under the same user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out I was only seeing this exception due to enabling `All Common Language Exceptions` in `Common Language Exception` dialog.

This exception appears to be thrown internally.